# Are Unicode names in Python language a good idea?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, interpreter

I know perfectly well that Python can handle unicode strings. But I want the interpreter to understand them so that I dont have to type

lambda=1.54

but

λ=1.54

(apart from the fact that 'lambda' is reserved)

Is this ever going to happen (or is there a way to enable this)? Are there reasons against this?

Comment: It was already added. Now, does that answer your question or do you really want to ask about drawbacks of this?

Comment: When you tried it, what error did you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python3:

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  5 2011, 22:09:30) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> λ=1.54
>>> print(λ)
1.54
>>>
```

Comment: (Aside: if you are using the Windows command prompt you may have problems typing and printing `λ`, but this isn't a Python-specific problem.)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for answering. Now I only have to get used to Python3 (and avoid habits like print w/o () )

Answer (score 4):

Python 2 only allowed ASCII identifiers but Python 3 allows additional unicode characters.  You can read this in the [Identifiers and Keywords](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) section of the Python 3 documentation.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/

Should answer your question.

Comment: Very interesting read in itself, which also covers my thoughts about (inter human) constraints imported into the language by allowing all of unicode.